# Can't draw Histogram on R, x "must be numeric"

Tags: r

country
cars
deaths
population

1
Belgium
467
112
10396
2
Czech Republic
373
135
10212
3
Denmark
354
68
5398
4
Germany
546
71
82532
5
Estonia
350
126
1351
6
Greece
348
147
11041
7
Spain
454
112
42345
8
France
491
92
59901
9
Ireland
385
94
4028
10
Italy
581
97
57888
11
Cyprus
448
160
730
12
Latvia
297
222
2319
13
Lithuania
384
218
3446
14
Luxembourg
659
109
452
15
Hungary
280
128
10117
16
Malta
525
33
400
17
Netherlands
429
49
16258
18
Austria
501
108
8114
19
Poland
314
150
38191
20
Portugal
572
124
10475
21
Slovenia
456
137
1996
22
Slovakia
222
112
5380
23
Finland
448
72
5220
24
Sweden
456
53
8976
25
United Kingdom
463
56
59652

I keep entering the following statement and it states "x" must be numeric and I have no clue why!

hist(cars,ylab = "Frecuencia por paises",xlab = "Automoviles por mil habitantes",main = "Histograma de automoviles por cada 1000 habitates",ylim = c(0,10),col = ("magenta"))

Comment: `x` clearly isn't numeric. [Please show your dataset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) the way we can make at least an educated guess. A reproducible example would be the ultimate goal, though.

Answer (score 0):

define your dataset (say as df)

```
#to convert cars column into numeric format
df$cars<-as.numeric(as.character(df$cars))

hist(df$cars,....)
```

... other arguements

Also u can try ggplot for better visualization

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(Country,Cars))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```